# Django REST framework not parsing UTF-8

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, django-rest-framework

I am trying to migrate my old backend to Djano REST framework. I have my old MySQL database with UTF-8. For example, in my database a name is saved as "Felipe NiÃ±o Arango".  I'm not sure, but I think drf should decode this in response "Felipe Niño Arango".

I'am trying passing the chartset to db options:

```
'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'latin1',
                    'use_unicode': True, }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have "Mojibake", as discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .  The fix for such is found [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) .  If you have trouble figuring out the details, provide more information, as discussed in both places.